# Correct way to find if spring context was started

Tags: spring, events, event-handling, lifecycle

In my spring bean I want to use send spring event functionality. The problem is event can't be sent if spring context was not initialized and my bean by some reasons can send events before that happen.

I used the following:

1. implement `ApplicationContextAware` and use `ConfigurableApplicationContext.isActive()` - this becomes true in the beginning of the context initialization phase
2. use `ConfigurableApplicationContext.isRunning()` - this throws exception `IllegalStateException("LifecycleProcessor not initialized...`
3. listen for `ContextRefreshedEvent` - this doesn't work because this is inner bean and is used as a property for the bean that implements `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`
4. implementing `SmartLifecycle` also doesn't work because for inner beans

So what is the *EASY* and correct way to determine if context is running and event can be sent?

Comment: The easy way, don't use an inner bean and implement `SmartLifecycle`. But isn't the real issue you need to fix the fact that you send events to early?

Comment: Yes - root issue is to prevent sending events too early. The way to find if spring is ready to deliver events.

Comment: I added bug https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14783 about ContextRefreshedEvent is not received by inner beans if outer bean implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is already fixed [SPR-13667](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13667) in spring 4.1.7.